# Can anyone point out why this contact form is not working correctly?

Tags: php, html

Good afternoon, I've recently launched a website and during testing I've found my contact form isn't working properly. I receive the emails to my account but there is no contact information or message content submitted. Anyone an idea what may be going wrong? Thank you

My HTML is:

```
</div>
                <div class="col-md-8 contact-right">
                    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
                        <input type="text" class="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="text" class="in-phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone">
                        <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message" ></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--contact end here-->
```

And PHP:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "enquiries@website.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: `name` != `"Name` and so on.

Comment: case-sensitive is the issue. $_POST['name'] is not same as $_POST['Name']

Comment: And you've got `$email = $_POST['phone'];`, doesn't look like its a matching pair either ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! It's working apart from the phone number part isn't displaying. I changed all to capitals, I'll have a look at it again.